# how to print jagged array using characters?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
char[][]tictactoe= {{'#','#'},{'#','#','#','#','#'},{'#','#','#','#'}};
System.out.println(tictactoe);
}
```

we want it to print # signs using a 2d array what am I doing wrong

Comment: How do you want to print it? Show the format...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
for(char[] innerArray : tictactoe) System.out.println(Arrays.asList(innerArray ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a loop:

```
char[][]tictactoe= {{'#','#'},{'#','#','#','#','#'},{'#','#','#','#'}};

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
for(char[] arr : tictactoe)
    sj.add(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Output:

```
[[#, #], [#, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #]]
```